# How do I change the date format of a DataBinder.Eval in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to change the datetime format so just the date will show up.

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterActions" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <span class="historyDate"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionListDate")%></span>
                    <span class="historyName"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LeadActionName")%></span><br />
                    <span class="historyNotes"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionListNote")%></span>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I'm guessing it's something in between the <% %>, but I'm not sure.

My code behind is:

```
<pre>
        protected void RepeaterActionsFill()
    {

        string sql = @"  select a.ActionListDate, a.LeadListID, 
a.ActionListNote, 
l.LeadActionName
from ActionLists as a
INNER JOIN LeadActions as l
ON a.LeadActionID = l.LeadActionID
where a.LeadListID = " + Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"].ToString());

        RepeaterActions.DataSource = DBUtil.FillDataReader(sql);
        RepeaterActions.DataBind();
    }
</pre>
```

Currently, it comes accross looking like this:

[image: HTML View]

And what I'm looking for is for the time stamp to be gone there.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is what I was looking for:

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterActions" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <span class="historyDate"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionListDate", "{0:M/d/yy}")%></span>
                    <span class="historyName"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LeadActionName")%></span><br />
                    <span class="historyNotes"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionListNote")%></span>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

give the format e.g:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionListDate", "{0:d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}") %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me to find even simplier form: `<%# Eval("StartDate", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" ) %>`

Answer (score 29):

`<%# string.Format("{0:ddd MMM yyyy}", Eval("ActionListDate"))%>`

Comment: that was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I put this in the code behind:

```
public string makeShortDate(object oDate)
{
    if (oDate is DBNull) {
        return "";
    } else {
        DateTime dDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oDate);
        string sDate = dDate.ToShortDateString();
        return sDate;
    }           
}
```

And use this in the XHTML:

`Text='<%# makeShortDate ( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyDate")) %>`'

You can modify this for any type.

Answer (score -1):

also you can change your tsql to the following or just remove the `Convert.ToInt32()`

```
string sql = string.Format(@"select a.ActionListDate, a.LeadListID, 
                            a.ActionListNote, 
                            l.LeadActionName
                            from ActionLists as a
                            INNER JOIN LeadActions as l
                            ON a.LeadActionID = l.LeadActionID
                            where a.LeadListID = {0};", Request["id"]);
```

Comment: How can you mark down something from 8 years ago!  Obviously methods have changed #fool

Answer (score -4):

Can't test this code right now but something along the lines of?

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionListDate").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>
```